# Помогите решить задачку роутер (маршрутизатор ) PHP с динамическими страницами с БД RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Есть роутер взят с паблика 
Суть задачи с БД достать  таблицу name(vasy) и выдать как ссылку мойсайт/vasy

```
<?php
//$GLOBALS['sitemap'] = array (
  //  '_404' => 'page404.php',   // Страница 404</span>
   // '/' => 'index.php',   // Главная страница
  //  '/news' => 'newspage.php',   // Новости - страница без параметров
   // '/stories(/[0-9]+)?' => 'storypage.php',  // С числовым параметром
    // Больше правил
//);
 require_once 'config/sitimap.php';

// Код роутера
class uSitemap {
    public $title = '';
    public $params = null;
    public $classname = '';
    public $data = null;

    public $request_uri = '';
    public $url_info = array();

    public $found = false;

    function __construct() {
        $this->mapClassName();
    }

    function mapClassName() {

        $this->classname = '';
        $this->title = '';
        $this->params = null;

        $map = &$GLOBALS['sitemap'];
        $this->request_uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        $this->url_info = parse_url($this->request_uri);
        $uri = urldecode($this->url_info['path']);
        $data = false;
        foreach ($map as $term => $dd) {
            $match = array();
            $i = preg_match('@^'.$term.'$@Uu', $uri, $match);
            if ($i > 0) {
                // Get class name and main title part
                $m = explode(',', $dd);
                $data = array(
                    'classname' => isset($m[0])?strtolower(trim($m[0])):'',
                    'title' => isset($m[1])?trim($m[1]):'',
                    'params' => $match,
                );
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($data === false) {
            // 404
            if (isset($map['_404'])) {
                // Default 404 page
                $dd = $map['_404'];
                $m = explode(',', $dd);
                $this->classname = strtolower(trim($m[0]));
                $this->title = trim($m[1]);
                $this->params = array();
            }
            $this->found = false;
        } else {
            // Found!
            $this->classname = $data['classname'];
            $this->title = $data['title'];
            $this->params = $data['params'];
            $this->found = true;
        }
        return $this->classname;
    }
}
$sm = new uSitemap();
$routed_file = $sm->classname; // Получаем имя файла для подключения через require()
require('/tpl/'.$routed_file); // Подключаем файлы статистических страниц

// P.S. Внутри подключённого файла Вы можете использовать параметры запроса,
// которые хранятся в свойстве $sm->params
?>
```

$GLOBALS вывел массив в отдельный файл 
если статическую страницу собираю все норм
с БД достаю по id 
'/news' => 'newspage.php',

а в newspage.php пишу это все работает

```
<?php
$ids = [3];
$books = R::loadAll('pages', $ids);
foreach ($books as $book)
?>
```

все работает, помогите пожалуйста подсказать заранее очень буду благодарен

Comment: Определитесь что у Вас работает, а что нет. Вы ведь не забываете о важности ";" в коде, для того чтобы отделить разную логику. Вот так же и с текстом сделайте.

Comment: Суть задачи с БД достать таблицу name(vasy) и выдать как ссылку мойсайт/vasy